# HP ALM 11.52 - OTA API - Check In/Out test cases with VB script

Tags: vba, excel, hp-alm

I am using OTA to upload test cases from excel to ALM.

I have used the excel add-in and have found it to be quite cumbersome for my project needs, so I am writing a custom script to accomplish the task.

**Note: Version Control is ON.**

I have version control on, therefore, I need to check out the created test case before I can add steps. Preferably, I'd like to be able to check in the test case again when I am complete. Is there a way to do this with the OTA api?

This is the script that I am using:

```
Sub UploadTC()

Dim QCConnection
Dim qcUserName, qcPassword, qcDomain, qcProj
Dim tsf, trmgr
Dim trfolder, trtest
Dim dsf, dstep, steplist
Dim TCR As Range
Dim cache As Range
Dim scount As Range
'Fields
Dim TCName As Range
Dim TCStep As Range
Dim TCDesc As Range
Dim TCExRe As Range
Dim TCComm As Range
Dim TCType As Range



'~~~These need to come from a user form. Temporary.
qcUserName = "ssoong01"
qcPassword = "*********"
qcDomain = "HUB"
qcProj = "*********"

Set QCConnection = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
'MsgBox ("Connect to QC Server")

QCConnection.InitConnectionEx "http://hpalm-qc.*****.net:8080/qcbin/"
'MsgBox ("Connection Established.")

QCConnection.Login qcUserName, qcPassword
'MsgBox ("Login Authenticated.")

QCConnection.Connect qcDomain, qcProj
'MsgBox ("Connected to Project.")

Set tsf = QCConnection.TestFactory
Set trmgr = QCConnection.TreeManager

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test Cases")

 'Create Project Folder
Set trfolder = trmgr.NodebyPath("Subject").AddNode(.Cells(3, 2))
trfolder.Post
'Loop through each row in sheet from A4
Set cache = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Values").Range("$A$3")
For Each TCR In .Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
    Set TCName = .Range(TCR.Offset(0, 1).Address)
    Set TCType = .Range(TCR.Offset(0, 7).Address)

    'If Folder Then
        If TCType.Value = "Folder" Then
            Set trfolder = trmgr.NodebyPath("Subject" & TCR.Value).AddNode(TCName.Value)
            trfolder.Post
    'If Test Case Then
        ElseIf TCType.Value = "MANUAL" Then
            'If cached TC name = current row TC name then skip
            If TCName = cache.Value Then
            'Add Test Case
            ElseIf TCName <> cache.Value Then
                Set trfolder = trmgr.NodebyPath("Subject" & TCR.Value)
                Set trtest = trfolder.TestFactory.AddItem(TCName.Value)
                    ' set values
                    trtest.Field("TS_NAME") = TCName
                    trtest.Field("TS_RESPONSIBLE") = qcUserName ' Designer
                    trtest.Field("TS_TYPE") = "MANUAL"

                    trtest.Post

            'Steps
            Set dsf = trtest.DesignStepFactory
            Set steplist = dsf.Newlist("[empty]")

            ' loop through all the steps
            Set scount = .Range(TCName.Address)
            Do
                Set TCStep = .Range(scount.Offset(0, 1).Address)
                Set TCDesc = .Range(scount.Offset(0, 2).Address)
                Set TCExRe = .Range(scount.Offset(0, 3).Address)
                Set TCComm = .Range(scount.Offset(0, 4).Address)

                Set dstep = dsf.AddItem(Null)
                    dstep.Field("DS_STEP_NAME") = TCStep.Value
                    dstep.Field("DS_DESCRIPTION") = TCDesc.Value
                    dstep.Field("DS_EXPECTED") = TCExRe.Value
                    Set scount = .Range(scount.Offset(1).Address)
            Loop Until scount.Value <> scount.Offset(-1).Value

            dstep.Post

                'cache TC name
                cache.Value = TCName.Value
            End If
        Else:
            MsgBox ("Invalid type at cell: " & TCR.Address)
        End If

Next TCR
```

HP Application Lifecycle Management

Application Lifecycle Management Edition 11.52.514

OTA Client 11.52.514.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can perform both check-in and check-out operations using the OTA API. It is described in detail in the documentation, and there are also some sample scripts there that shows how it can be done. I assume that you know where to find the OTA API reference/documenation?

Here is a sample script from the documentation, which shows how to write a function that performs a check-out of a test:

```
Public Function CheckoutTest(tst As Test, comment$, _
    ByRef CanContinue As Boolean) As Object

    On Error GoTo checkout_err
    CanContinue = True

    Dim fVersionControl As VCS
    Set fVersionControl = tst.VCS

    If IsNull(fVersionControl) Then
        Set CheckoutTest = Null
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set CheckoutTest = fVersionControl
    fVersionControl.CheckOut -1, comment, False

Exit Function
checkout_err:
    CanContinue = False
    ErrHandler err, "CheckoutTest", "", FATAL_ERROR
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers I was looking for in the OTA documentation. Definitely a resource I should utilise more often.